# How to store mutlimedia files in Cassandra?

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0, multimedia, bigdata

I'm a newbie to Cassandra. I'm trying to store mutlimedia(photo, video, audio) files in Cassandra using blob. How is do it? there any other alternative to do the same?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on how large the files are, but large objects and files are more easily stored in MongoDB. With Cassandra you could split the files up into chunks of a smaller size and make a file correspond to a row, with the chunks as column values.

Comment: thanks! Can you provide an example or point towards it? I'm been looking a solution without luck for while

Answer (score 0):

How large are your files? Blobs in cassandra can be in theory 2gb large - but in the real world blobs should be less than a few mb for performance reasons.

You can of course chunk your files up into smaller pieces and reassemble them as needed (ideal while streaming data).

But you can and probably should go polyglot - c* for metadata and some object store as aws s3 or rados on ceph for selfhosting and put just the links to the bulk data to c*.